# Golang: GS1 Barcode Generation

Tags: go, barcode

Hello i am trying to generate a GS1-128 Barcode in golang and currently i am able to get it to render the same as a GS1-128 Barcode but it scans as code-128 barcode and it has `<FNC1>` instead of `(`

```
encoded, _ := code128.Encode("(343)12332(23)32123123")
key := barcode.Register(encoded)
var width = 72.0
var height = 15.0
barcode.Barcode(pdf, key, 50, 50, width, height, false)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

GS1-128 *is* code128.  GS1 just uses a specific encoding of the data within the code128 symbology.  For your example text, (343)12332(23)32123123, the numbers in parentheses are application-identifiers that indicate how to interpret the following data value.  And those parentheses are for the human-readable text displayed below the barcode.  The actual barcode uses the <FNC1> code to indicate that the next set of numbers are an application identifier.

Unfortunately, 343 is an invalid AI, so it is not possible to dissect your example any further.

If you would like to compare your barcodes with a validating barcode generator, you can use the bwip-js public API (I am the author of bwip-js).  The following is the URL for your example text:

https://api-bwipjs.metafloor.com/?bcid=gs1-128&text=(343)12332(23)32123123&includetext&padding=10

Comment: This actually really helped! I was able to figure it out :) Thank you for your insight and your website!